# How would I be able to make a variable within a function available in the global scope

Tags: swift, scope, concatenation

I am trying to access the finalText variable in a separate @IBAction function but I am unable since it is part of the viewDidLoad function. When I move the finalText variable outside of the viewDidLoad function, I get an error because it does not recognize the variables in concatenating in the finalText Variable. Is there a way to be able to call on this variable or move it the global scope? Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MenuControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var ageField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var genderField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var relationshipField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var budgetField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var extraMention1Field: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var extraMention2Field: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var extraMention3Field: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {     
        ageField.delegate = self
        genderField.delegate = self
        relationshipField.delegate = self
        budgetField.delegate = self
        extraMention1Field.delegate = self
        extraMention2Field.delegate = self
        extraMention3Field.delegate = self
        
        let ageText: String = ageField.text!
        let genderText: String = genderField.text!
        let relationshipText: String = relationshipField.text!
        let budgetText: String = budgetField.text!
        let extraMentions1Text: String = extraMention1Field.text!
        let extraMentions2Text: String = extraMention2Field.text!
        let extraMentions3Text: String = extraMention3Field.text!
        
        let finalText = "Give me 5 gift ideas for someone who has the following characteristics" + ageText + "," + genderText + "," + relationshipText + "." + "This person also posses the following characteristics/personalities:" + extraMentions1Text + "," + extraMentions2Text + "," + extraMentions3Text + "." + "My budget is the following:" + budgetText
    }
    
    @IBAction func enterTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print(finalText)
    }
```

I have tried moving around the finalText variable, but I keep getting errors.

Comment: Make a computed var property: `var finalText = { ... }`?

Answer (score 0):

Half of the code you put in `viewDidLoad` doesn't belong there. `viewDidLoad` is called once when the view controller is first created and long before it is visible to the user and long before any of the text fields will have been filled in by the user.

Making `finalText` a computed property is one solution if you need to access its value from more than just the `enterTapped` method.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MenuControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var ageField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var genderField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var relationshipField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var budgetField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var extraMention1Field: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var extraMention2Field: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var extraMention3Field: UITextField!

    private var finalText: String {
        let ageText = ageField.text!
        let genderText = genderField.text!
        let relationshipText = relationshipField.text!
        let budgetText = budgetField.text!
        let extraMentions1Text = extraMention1Field.text!
        let extraMentions2Text = extraMention2Field.text!
        let extraMentions3Text = extraMention3Field.text!
        
        return "Give me 5 gift ideas for someone who has the following characteristics \(ageText), \(genderText), \(relationshipText). This person also posses the following characteristics/personalities: \(extraMentions1Text), \(extraMentions2Text), \(extraMentions3Text). My budget is the following: \(budgetText)"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad() // Make sure to call this
   
        ageField.delegate = self
        genderField.delegate = self
        relationshipField.delegate = self
        budgetField.delegate = self
        extraMention1Field.delegate = self
        extraMention2Field.delegate = self
        extraMention3Field.delegate = self
    }
    
    @IBAction func enterTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print(finalText)
    }
```

Note that I replaced all of string concatenation for building the long string.

Also note the addition of the call to `super.viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: Perfect thank you, just learning swift so thanks for the explanation :)!

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to mark questions that solved your issue as accepted and/or upvote helpful answers (once you have enough reputation).